# How to add pagination in magento frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add pagination in magento front end
[image]?

Comment: please try this link, this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664130/magento-paginate-a-custom-collection

Comment: Not working.Please tell me any other soluction

Comment: your getting collection from Block @SumaJ  Try This Link http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-adding-pagination-to-custom-collection/

Answer (score 0):

For custom pagination check this link or you can check **Github** also or any extension for the pagination in **Magento** front-end

> http://inchoo.net/magento/pagination-custom-collection/